# Reload page or div using RJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rjs

I have a 'like'-counter in a rails project. Whenever one clicks this 'like'-link I want to add one to the like_counter in the database. The logic works well and the database is updated, but I cannot figure out how to set up the Ajax Request correctly so it refreshes the page or the div when completed.

In my view this looks as follows:

```
<%= link_to_remote 'like', :url => {
                           :controller => 'projects', 
                           :action => 'like_it', 
                           :id=> @project.id }%>
```

The controller:

```
def like_it
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @project.update_like
    render :update do |page|
       page.reload
    end
end
```

the update_like method is in the model and just adds one to the counter and saves the project (this part works).
As for the page.reload I Firefox throws an RJS-Error: ReferenceError: Reload is not defined. And the page is not reloaded

What do I do wrong? Is there a more distinguished way to just reload the div containing the counter? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
render :update do |page|
    page << "window.location.reload()"
end
```